# Trying to match this using regular expressions in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use regular expressions to match certain lines in a file, but I am having some trouble.

The file contains text like this:

```
Mario, 123456789
Luigi, 234-567-890
Nancy, 345 5666 77533
Bowser, 348759823745908732589
Peach, 534785
Daisy, 123-456-7890
```

I'm trying to match just the numbers as either XXX-XXX-XXX or XXX XXX XXX pattern.

I've tried a few different ways, but it always expects something I don't want it to or it tell me everything is false.

I'm using PowerShell to do this.

At first I tried:

```
{$match = $i -match "\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}|\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{3}"
Write-Host $match}
```

But when I do that it matches the long strong of numbers and `XXX-XXX-XXXXX`.

I read something saying that n would match the exact quantity, so I tried that...

```
{$match = $i -match "\d{n3}\-\d{n3}\-\d{n3}|\d{n3}\ \d{n3}\ \{n3}"
Write-Host $match}
```

That made everything false...

So I tried

```
{$match = $i -match "\d\n{3}\-\d\n{3}\-\d\n{3}|\d\n{3}\ \d\n{3}\ \d\n{3}"
```

I also tried the lazy quantifier, `?`:

```
{$match = $i -match "\d{3?}\-\d{3?}\-\d{3?}|\d{3?}\ \{3?}\ \{3?}"
Write-Host $match}
```

Still false...

The final thing I tried was this...

```
{$match = $i -match "\d[0-9\{3\}\-\d[0-9]\{3\}\-\d[0-9]{3\}|\d[0-9]\{3\}\ \d[0-9]\{3}\ \d[0-9]\{3\}"<br>
Write-Host $match}
```

Still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern gives two matches:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}'}
```

Luigi, 234-567-890
Daisy,
123-456-7890

If you want to exclude the last match, add the '$' anchor (represents the end of the string:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}$'}
```

Luigi, 234-567-890

If you want to be very specific and match lines from start to end (use the ^ anchor, denotes the start of the string):

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '^\w+,\s+\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}[-|\s]\d{3}$'}
```

Luigi, 234-567-890

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer is the closest.  The `{3}` matches exactly 3 characters.  I think the `n` you saw was supposed to represent any number, not an actual `n` character.  The reason it matches the long strings is that you only specified that the match must find 3 digits, dash or space, 3 digits, dash or space, then 3 more digits.  You did not specify that it doesn't count if there are more digits after that.

To not match when there is a number after, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs).

```
(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{3})(?!\d)
```

Alternatively, if you want to only match at the end of the line, possibly with trailing space

```
(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{3})\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\d+[- ])+\d+/
```

It's better not to have so rigid regular expressions, unless you are absolutely sure there that your input will not change.

So this regex matches at least a digit, then greedily searches for more digits followed by a space or a dash. This is also repeated as much as possible then followed by at least another digit.

Answer (score 0):

As Gideon said, your first is the best place to start.

```
"\b\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}\b|\b\d{3}\ \d{3}\ \d{3}\b"
```

The `\b` special character added before and after each statement is a word boundary - basically a space or newline or punctuation like a period or comma. This ensures that `9999` doesn't match, but `999.` does.

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating data in PowerShell, it usually is a good idea to create objects representing the data (after all, PowerShell is all about objects). Filtering based on object properties is usually easier and more robust. Your problem is a good example.
Here is what we are after:

- **the persons**: $persons
- **where**: where
- **the number of that person**: $_.number
- **matches**: -match
- **the pattern**
- **starting with three digits**: ^\d{3}
- **followed by three digits between dashes or spaces**: (-\d{3}-|\ \d{3}\ )
- **ending on three digits**: \d{3}$

Below is the entire script:

```
$persons = import-csv -Header "name", "number" -delimiter "," data.csv
$persons | where {$_.number -match "^\d{3}(\-\d{3}\-|\ \d{3}\ )\d{3}$"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Select-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

```
Select-String '(\d{3}[ -]){2}\d{3}$' .\file.txt | % {$_.Line}
```